# $this->validation custom redirect

Tags: validation, redirect, laravel-5

I have a form with four tab so after validation it redirect me on first tab always, but i want it redirect me on that which have error message

Here is my code

```
$this->validate($request,
                [
                'name' => 'required|min:3|alpha_spaces', 
                'date_of_birth' => 'required|date|date_format:"Y-m-d"', 
                'place_of_birth' => 'required',
                'nationality' => 'required',
                'address' => 'required',
                'port_name' => 'required',
                'contact_number' => 'required|digits_between:8,15|numeric',
                'religion' => 'required',
                'education_level' => 'required',
                'marital_status' => 'required',
                'interview_method' => 'required',
                'can_be_interviewed_via' => 'required',
                'date_to' => 'required',
                'date_from' => 'required',
                'country' => 'required',
                ]);
```

and for redirect i m using on every tab i m using submit button with hidden filed selecttab

```
if ($data['selecttab'] == 'tab0') { 
            return redirect("fdws/".$id."/edit?tab=tab0");
        }elseif($data['selecttab'] == 'tab1'){ 
            return redirect("fdws/".$id."/edit?tab=tab1");
        }elseif($data['selecttab'] == 'tab2'){ 
            return redirect("fdws/".$id."/edit?tab=tab2");  
        }else{ 
            return redirect("fdws/".$id."/edit?tab=tab3");
        }
```

When no validation apply it work fine

Comment: I modified my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found,
I done like that and its working fine :)

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'can_be_interviewed_via' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect("fdws/".$id."/edit?tab=tab3")
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

<del>Before you call your `$this->validate($request, ...` set `$redirect` to the result of your `if ($data['selecttab'] == 'tab0') { ...` statement. Therefore, I suggest first do your if statement and have a variable named `$redirect` that catches the result of the if statment

    if ($data['selecttab'] == 'tab0') { 
            $redirect = "fdws/".$id."/edit?tab=tab0";
        }elseif($data['selecttab'] == 'tab1'){ 
            $redirect = "fdws/".$id."/edit?tab=tab1";
        }elseif($data['selecttab'] == 'tab2'){ 
            $redirect = "fdws/".$id."/edit?tab=tab2";  
        }else{ 
            $redirect = "fdws/".$id."/edit?tab=tab3";
        }

And then `$this->validate(...)`.</del>

Scratch that! I made a big mistake. [According to](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#controller-validation) official Laravel 5.0 documentation, and also looking at the `Illuminate\Foundation\ValidatesRequests` trait, when using `Controller Validation`, it is NOT possible to just chose the redirect route without modification to the traits or other codes. I think using [Form Request](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#form-request-validation) will give you the power you want with a lot less hassle.

Comment: $redirect = "fdws/".$id."/edit?tab=tab3";
   $this->validate($request,
    [
    'can_be_interviewed_via' => 'required',
    ]); not working

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5 use Middleware as helpers for controllers and routes. This will help you a lot.